# How to clear the value of apex:inputTextarea in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I have below HTML code

```
<apex:inputTextarea value="{!noteValue}" rows="8" id="notes-area" cols="100" />
```

and then there is a button which is calling below JS code

```
console.log('inside JS method');

document.getElementById("notes-area").value = ''
document.querySelector('textarea[id="notes-area"]').value = '';
```

I also set the apex variable to `null` but still no luck.

I can see log in the console but still, it doesn't clear the value from the `inputTextarea`, could someone please suggest?

Comment: Is this a standard controller or a custom controller? This looks like you're just creating JS with button code. If it were a custom controller, you'd want to use getters and setters with a method to first explicitly set the values to blank strings in the controller then pass them to the page. Without the full context, I can't advise further. It's just been too long since I've written any VF.

Comment: more detail is required here -- the VF page (essential elements only) and the corresponding Apex controller that deals with `noteValue`. Use [edit]